# Why is my hashmap clearing some of its values?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to create a map for a tree. It maps the column number (horizontal depth) to the list of nodes with that horizontal depth.

When I use the below code, somehow the map gets overwritten by the else block.

The tree I am testing on:
Input: `root = [3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`, from https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-vertical-order-traversal/

```java
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
if (!map.containsKey(col)) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(n.val);
    map.put(col, array); 
} else {
    map.get(col).add(n.val);
}
```

Output: `[[],[15],[],[]]`
The other lists on the map were cleared...

When I use this block, the map is built as expected:

```java
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
if (!map.containsKey(col)) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
    map.put(col, array); 
}
map.get(col).add(n.val);
```

Output: [[9],[3,15],[20],[7]]

So I have this block that works, but I don't understand why the first one doesn't

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(int n)` does not work the way you think it does. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(n.val)` creates an *empty* `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of `n.val`. Not an `ArrayList` containing `n.val`. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)). Try `new ArrayList<>(List.of(n.val))`.

Comment: It’s an interesting question. You may want to train creating a [mre], though.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, using "List.of(n.val)" fixed the first approach. Still need to step through it but its is making more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

`new ArrayList<Integer>(5)` creates a new **empty** list with initial capacity 5, which isn't at all what you want. What you wanted was:

```
var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);
```

Or possibly if you want to one-liner it `new ArrayList<Integer>(List.of(5))`.

More generally this concept ('map a key to a list of values; create the list upon inserting the first value and add to an existing list otherwise') comes a ton, and there's a nicer way to do it:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent(col, k -> new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(n.val);
```

As the name suggests, `computeIfAbsent` will run the provided lambda (the stuff after the arrow) **only** if key `col` is absent (is not in the map at all). In this case, it runs the code, and sets it as the value to go with key `col`. The method call itself (`computeIfAbsent`) returns the generated value if that happened, or the existing value if that happened. Either way, that's the list you want to add to. Hence, one line, no need for `if` shenanigans.

Answer (score 0):

*"... So I have this block that works, but I don't understand why the first one doesn't ..."*

You've misinterpreted the *[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#constructor-summary)* constructor parameter.

Here is an excerpt of the *JavaDoc*.

> *public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)*
>
> *Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.*
>
> ***Parameters**:*
> *initialCapacity - the initial capacity of the list*

Thus, supplying an *int* will not append the value.

A quick solution to this is to wrap the value in a *[List#of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E))* call.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(List.of(n.val));
```

You can also use a class initializer, which I'm failing to find a resource for.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>() {{ add(n.val); }};
```